# ASP.NET MVC Race Condition? Factory Singleton Static Dictionary

Tags: c#, singleton, factory

I have the following singleton class that serves as a factory for creating objects in my web application.  However, I'm seeing that I'm getting some sort of race condition during load testing.  Is there a better pattern I should follow?

```
public class SearchProviderFactory {
    private static SearchProviderFactory factory = null;        
    private static Dictionary<string, Type> providerMap = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

    private SearchProviderFactory() {
        // Error on the line below
        providerMap.Add("company_name", Type.GetType("MyApp.CompanySearchProvider"));
        providerMap.Add("job_title", Type.GetType("MyApp.JobTitleSearchProvider"));
    }

    public static SearchProviderFactory Instance {
        get {
            if (factory == null) {
                factory = new SearchProviderFactory();
            }

            return factory;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error, even though it seems the private constructor should never be called more than once.

```
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at MyApp.SearchProviderFactory..ctor() in c:\MyApp\_scm\app\src\trunk\MyApp\SearchProviderFactory.cs:line 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost the same as the one the sample code on the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) discussing Singleton implementation in C#. That article is pretty nice, I recommend it.

Their recommendation is to add a lock() statement to implement a critical section, using an. In your code, that would be something like:

```
public class SearchProviderFactory {
    private static volatile SearchProviderFactory factory;        
    private static Dictionary<string, Type> providerMap = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

    private SearchProviderFactory() {
        // Error on the line below
        providerMap.Add("company_name", Type.GetType("MyApp.CompanySearchProvider"));
        providerMap.Add("job_title", Type.GetType("MyApp.JobTitleSearchProvider"));
    }

    public static SearchProviderFactory Instance {
        get {
            if (factory == null) {
                lock (providerMap)
                {
                    if (factory == null) {
                        factory = new SearchProviderFactory();
                    }
                }
            }

            return factory;
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't compile this code, much less did a stress test on it. If you try it, please let me know if this works!

Comment: I actually just decided to call the Instance method in my global init to ensure this wouldn't happen again.

Comment: There are some nicer ways to implement this in newer versions of .NET. I rarely see the double null check + locking technique used these days. Most people go with a `Lazy<T>` wrapper now.